# autobahn js + thruway php error in connection esablishment

Tags: php, wamp, thruway, autobahnjs

I'm using a **PHP thruway library** + **autobahn.js**.

Right now I am trying to execute the example from thruway documentation. I ran a `SimpleWebRouter` and tried to establish connection using `autobahn.js`.

I changed a listener ip to `0.0.0.0:9090`, but autobahn still returns an error in connection establishment.

> Unreachable

But server is reachable.

```
var connection = new autobahn.Connection({url: 'ws://((site_url)):9090/', realm: 'realm1'});

connection.onopen = function (session) {

    // 1) subscribe to a topic
    function onevent(args) {
        console.log("Event:", args[0]);
    }
    session.subscribe('com.myapp.hello', onevent);

    // 2) publish an event
    session.publish('com.myapp.hello', ['Hello, world!']);

    // 3) register a procedure for remoting
    function add2(args) {
        return args[0] + args[1];
    }
    session.register('com.myapp.add2', add2);

    // 4) call a remote procedure
    session.call('com.myapp.add2', [2, 3]).then(
        function (res) {
            console.log("Result:", res);
        }
    );
};
connection.onclose = function(reason, details) {
    console.log(reason);console.log(details);
} 
connection.open();
```

Comment: Make sure the libraries speak a compatible version of the Web Sockets protocol. I myself [found out the hard way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48818453/websockets-are-rachet-autobahn-from-npm-compatible/48828422#48828422) that autobahn.js (.9+) implements a newer version of the protocol than Ratchet. You may be encountering a similar problem here.