# Websockets: Are Rachet & autobahn from npm compatible?

Tags: websocket, ratchet, autobahnws

I'm experimenting with the [Ratchet php library](http://socketo.me/). In particular, I've been trying to integrate their [push integration](http://socketo.me/docs/push) demo into a React application.

Their demo references [a seemingly one-off version of the autobahn JS library](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/cboden/fcae978cfc016d506639c5241f94e772/raw/e974ce895df527c83b8e010124a034cfcf6c9f4b/autobahn.js), which works against my server implementation (a near duplicate of their demo).

However, when I try to use [autobahn JS from npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autobahn) everything melts down. It seems this implementes a newer version of the Web Sockets protocol?

The one-off version of autobahn passes `wamp` for the `Sec-WebSocket-Protocol` header, which Ratchet seems to support. The npm version of autobahn passes `wamp.2.json, wamp.2.msgpack`...

Digging through the Ratchet code I found [this](https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet/blob/master/src/Ratchet/WebSocket/WsServerInterface.php)

> If any component in a stack supports a WebSocket sub-protocol return
>   each supported in an array

So I implemented `Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServerInterface` as such on my component

```php
public function getSubProtocols()
{
    return ['wamp.2.json', 'wamp.2.msgpack'];
}
```

Now the connection attempt gets a little further along, but still blows up

> failing transport due to protocol violation: unexpected message type 0

Then the client fails to close the connection

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'close' on 'WebSocket': The
>   code must be either 1000, or between 3000 and 4999. 1002 is neither.

What's going on here; does Ratchet support an older version of the Web Socket protocol, or is there a way to get these two libraries talking successfully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two libraries are not compatible, per [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet/issues/555).

> Autobahn 0.9+ implements wampv2, we have to use
>   autobahn 0.8, and I also don't find it on npm. Instead I find [wamp1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wamp1),
>   but I haven't tested it yet.